# Help With Grab Brush In Sculpt Mode

Tags: sculpting

I want to do something similar to this

https://youtu.be/R-I2l1G8CaI?t=2m17s

I'm trying to grab the back of the "head" but what I get is something like this

[image]

My sculpt is mirrored along the x-axis and so is the one in the YouTube video. But when I try to grab the back of the head, it looks like a butt while that in the video does not. Please help.

Comment: Turn your strength all the way up, zoom out a little more, and grab the very edge of the skull.

Comment: @Akados No buddy, still got the "butt"

Comment: You'll need to grab as close to that center back edge as possible.

Comment: Maybe uncheck Front Faces Only in the brush settings, it could work for your case. But as you can see from the video on 1:48 the tutor faces the same problem and generally this indeed can happen when sculpting from only one angle. Use several viewport windows

Comment: @MrZak Unchecking "Front Faces Only" did the trick. Please put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i gathered from the comments, your question has already been answered. For future readers:- Uncheck "**Front faces only**" in the brush tool settings[image]